# Generate an incremental index in the table

Tags: javascript

how can I do  for this function below to generate an incremental index in the table? Names are being generated right.

I thought of an incremental variable (`a`), something like that.

```
    function sortear()
    {
        var a = 1;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'prize',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'employees=' + $('#employees').val() + "&sorted=" + sorteados,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#loading').modal();
            },

            success: function(data) {


                $('#loading').modal('hide');

                if (data == null) {
                    window.alert('Todos os nomes foram sorteados');
                    $('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    return;
                }
                
                $('#employee').html(data.name);
                $('#myModal').modal();

                $('#sorted tbody').append('<tr><td>' + a + '</td><td>' + data.name + '</td></tr>');

                sorteados.push(data.name);
                a++;
            },

            error: function() {

            }
        });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You have to declare `var a = 1;` **outside** of the `sortear` function. Otherwise the index will always be `1` since on each call `a` will be redeclared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the length of `<tr>` and sum 1:

```
/*...*/

// store the element in a variable to reuse it
const $sortedTbody = $('#sorted tbody');

// in the first iteration lenght will be 0, so it will print 1, then 2, etc
$sortedTbody.append('<tr><td>' + ($sortedTbody.children().length + 1) + '</td><td>' + data.name + '</td></tr>');

/*...*/
```